# Seat Picker with js canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

so I am making a seat selector/picker for a bus/plane with js and html with a canvas and I got to the point where I could create a set of seats from the number of rows and columns input but now I am stuck on the selection part of it. I don't know how to let the user click the seat and then how to store it. If there is a better way of making a parameter-controlled seat picker I would love to hear it, I'm not picky with what tools I use to get something done.

The end goal for this is to have users pick seats but be able to see where babies are seated and to
tell them what noise level to expect from low to high depending on the distance from the baby. I don't know if this will help but just in case. :)

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("seats");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const seatSize = (window.innerWidth / 10);
const seatGap = 1.25;

var seatRows = 14;
var seatColumns = 4;
var busLength = (seatRows * seatSize * seatGap) + (seatSize * 2) - seatSize * (seatGap - 1);
var busWidth = (seatColumns * seatSize) + (seatSize);


canvas.width = busWidth + 20;
canvas.height = busLength + 20;

ctx.font = .15 * busWidth + "px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = "grey"
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Front", busWidth / 2 + 5, seatSize * 1.5);

ctx.strokeStyle = "gray";
ctx.lineWidth = "2";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.roundRect(10, 10, busWidth, busLength, [5]);
ctx.stroke();

var rowInstance = 0;
var columnInstance = 0;
var seatNumber = 1;

while (rowInstance < seatRows) {
  while (columnInstance < seatColumns) {
    if (columnInstance < seatColumns / 2) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = "gray";
      ctx.lineWidth = "2";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.roundRect(columnInstance * seatSize + 10, (rowInstance * seatSize * seatGap) + (seatSize * 2) + 10, seatSize, seatSize, [5]);
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.font = seatSize / 2 + "px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "grey"
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.fillText(seatNumber, columnInstance * seatSize + seatSize - (seatSize / 2), (rowInstance * seatSize * seatGap) + (seatSize * 2.65) + 10);

      columnInstance++;
      seatNumber++;
    } else {
      // Seats
      ctx.strokeStyle = "gray";
      ctx.lineWidth = "2";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.roundRect(columnInstance * seatSize + seatSize + 10, (rowInstance * seatSize * seatGap) + (seatSize * 2) + 10, seatSize, seatSize, [5]);
      ctx.stroke();
      // Seat Numbers
      ctx.font = seatSize / 2 + "px Arial";
      ctx.fillStyle = "grey"
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.fillText(seatNumber, columnInstance * seatSize + seatSize * 2 - (seatSize / 2), (rowInstance * seatSize * seatGap) + (seatSize * 2.65) + 10);

      seatNumber++;
      columnInstance++;
    }
  }

  rowInstance++;
  columnInstance = 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="seats"></canvas>
```

I have looked into ways on how to make things selectable with canvas but all the ones I could find require you to know the coordinates of each shape and since my objects are responsive and change it doesn't work.

Comment: First question that popped my mind was: Why use canvas in the first place? Do you have plans to allow a user to save as image the entire bus / airplane seats occupancy state as image? No? then I think there's better / simpler ways to achieve the desired. From SVG to simple HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

I see this have been sitting for a while, I hope I can still be useful for this matter.

Let's break your request in a few parts:

1. Prepare for clicking detection.

- It would be interesting to create an array containing the position of each seat, such as:

```
var seatArray = [["seat1", 100, 200, "not clicked"], ["seat2", 200, 200, "clicked"], etc..];
```

- You can always use the ".push" method to append according to the number of seats on the vehicle inside your while loop. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push
- Once you have that, a function can be created to fill the coordinates of the last click:

```
var clickX = 0;
var clickY = 0;
canvas.onmouseup = function (e){

    // Here we get the global clicking coordinates and subtract the starting position of the canvas
    clickX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    clickY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    // Check if the click corresponds to the position of a seat
    checkClick();
}
```

- Now it is necessary to check if the last click is within boundaries of a seat, called in the previous section.

```
function checkClick(){
    for(let i = 0; i < seatArray.length; i++){
        // Extract the data from the seatArray
        let currentSeat = seatArray[0];
        let posX = currentSeat[1];
        let posY = currentSeat[2];
        let click = currentSeat[3];

        // Create and initialize a variable which will determine the click
        let isClicked = 0;
        let colour = "grey";
        
        // Determine the end of the boundaries for X and Y coordinates
        let Xbound = posX + width;
        let Ybound = posY + height;
        
        // Check if the click was within the boundaries for horizontal and vertial axis
        let withinXboundaries = (clickX >= posX) && (clickX <= Xbound);
        let withinYboundaries = (clickY >= posY) && (clickY <= Ybound);
        
        // If within boundaries on both, then it's clicked
        isClicked = withinXboundaries && withinYboundaries;
    
        // Now, update the array
        if(isClicked){
            currentSeat[3] = "clicked";
        }
    }
}
```

- To colour your seat properly, where you wrote "ctx.strokeStyle = 'gray'", you'll need to perform a check, such as:

```
if(seatArray[seatNumber][3] == "clicked"){
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
} else {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "grey";
}
```

2. Update the screen:

- First, you need to transform your while loop into a function:

```
function drawSeats(){
    // Insert your while loop here ...
}
```

- Before calling it, we need to make sure the canvas is blank, so create a clearCanvas() function:

```
function clearCanvas(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

- Then we need to call it from time to time:

```
setInterval(() => {
    clearCanvas();
    drawSeats();
}, scanTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic for rendering seats can be moved to a separate render function that takes a seat object.

You will need to encapsulate this logic into a class for reuse, readability, and maintainability.

You will also need to use `requestAnimationFrame` to create a loop for re-rendering.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("seats");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// The main entry with the loop logic
const main = () => {
  const seating = new BusSeating(14, 4);
  const update = () => {
    seating.update();
    seating.render(ctx);
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
};

// Mouse listeners
let mousePos = { x: 0, y: 0 },
  clickPos = null;
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
canvas.addEventListener("click", handleMouseClick);

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  mousePos = { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY };
}

function handleMouseClick(e) {
  clickPos = { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY };
}

// Collision check
function isCollision(point, bounds) {
  return (
    point.x > bounds.x &&
    point.x < bounds.x + bounds.width &&
    point.y > bounds.y &&
    point.y < bounds.y + bounds.height
  );
}

// Handles rendering a bus seating chart
class BusSeating {
  static defaultSeatOptions = {
    gap: 1.5,
  };

  constructor(rows, cols, options = {}) {
    const opts = { ...BusSeating.defaultSeatOptions, ...options };
    this.state = {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
      rows: rows,
      cols: cols,
      gap: opts.gap,
      seats: [],
    };
    this.setup();
  }

  update() {
    if (clickPos) {
      for (let seat of this.state.seats) {
        if (isCollision(clickPos, seat)) {
          seat.selected = !seat.selected;
          clickPos = null;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  setup() {
    const size = window.innerWidth / 10;
    const { rows, cols, gap } = this.state;

    this.state.width = cols * size + size;
    this.state.height = rows * size * gap + size * (3 - gap);

    for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        this.state.seats.push({
          x: col * size + (col < cols / 2 ? 10 : size + 10),
          y: row * size * gap + size * 2 + 10,
          width: size,
          height: size,
          number: row * cols + col + 1,
          selected: false,
        });
      }
    }
  }

  render(ctx) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    const seatSize = window.innerWidth / 10;
    const seatGap = this.gap;
    const seatRows = this.rows;
    const seatColumns = this.cols;
    const busLength = this.state.height;
    const busWidth = this.state.width;

    ctx.canvas.width = busWidth + 20;
    ctx.canvas.height = busLength + 20;

    ctx.font = 0.15 * busWidth + "px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("Front", busWidth / 2 + 5, seatSize * 1.5);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "gray";
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.roundRect(10, 10, busWidth, busLength, [5]);
    ctx.stroke();

    for (let seat of this.state.seats) {
      this.renderSeat(ctx, seat);
    }
  }

  renderSeat(ctx, seat) {
    // Border
    ctx.strokeStyle = "gray";
    ctx.lineWidth = "2";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.roundRect(seat.x, seat.y, seat.width, seat.height, [5]);
    ctx.stroke();
    // Number
    const x = seat.x + Math.floor(seat.width / 2);
    const y = seat.y + Math.floor(seat.height / 2);
    ctx.font = seat.height / 2 + "px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(seat.number, x, y);
    // Highlight
    let highlightColor = null;
    if (seat.selected) {
      highlightColor = "hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.5)";
    } else if (isCollision(mousePos, seat)) {
      highlightColor = "hsla(60, 100%, 50%, 0.5)";
    }
    if (highlightColor) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.roundRect(seat.x, seat.y, seat.width, seat.height, [5]);
      ctx.fillStyle = highlightColor;
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="seats"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why use canvas in the first place? :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah, this should just be a React, Vue, Angular, Svelte, Lit, etc... component.

Comment: I'm not saying a library or framework should back this up. Often times vanilla JS can suffice. My argument is that Canvas performs really badly in sharpness when responsiveness is needed. SVG or even better some responsive HTML elements might be a far simpler solution than the initial OP's idea. I mean... who knows, perhaps an Image-data is really needed...